# java.sql.SQLException: Geometry byte string must be little endian

Tags: java, mysql, sql, prepared-statement, sqlexception

I want to use the `contains` function to get all values whose `title` or `question` contains a certain value. However, I get this error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Geometry byte string must be little endian.
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRowFast(MysqlIO.java:2076)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:1932)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet(MysqlIO.java:3426)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:488)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:3131)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:2299)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2722)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2322)
>         at SQL.Select.getRecentQuestions(Select.java:447)
>         at org.apache.jsp.Questions_jsp._jspService(Questions_jsp.java:198)
>         at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>         at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
>         at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
>         at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>         at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
>         at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
>         at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

This is the code:

```
public String getRecentQuestions(String search) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select title, question_id from questions where contains(title, ?) or contains(question, ?) limit 20");
        ps.setString(1, search);
        ps.setString(2, search);
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder("");
        while (rs.next()) {
            sb.append("<a href='Question.jsp?question=").append(rs.getInt(2)).append("'><h2>");
            sb.append(rs.getString(1));
            sb.append("</h2></a>");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

My PreparedStatement is valid, the `title` column data type is `varchar`, and the `question` column data type is `varchar` as well.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mysql use **instr(str, substr)** instead of **contains**

maybe you can try **instr** or **like**

Answer (score 1):

Shawn Xu is right.
you can use "**INSTR(str, substr)**" for fuzzy query on text.
ex: **where INSTR( content, "test" ) > 0**,
"INSTR" is more efficient than "like"

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Doj sry, i do not have enough reputation to comment... T T